# How to fix dataframe split and explode methods not working correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, rows

I have this function to split the 'text' column with each column called 'emotion'. However this is working correctly with a premade dataframe, but is not working with a big dataframe. Since when applying the function, it creates another column with a list of the 'text' column.

```py
def splitting_rows(df, subset, subset_explode, split_value='\s+'):
    '''
    Creates new rows splitting the subset targeted.
    Transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values 

    :param df: dataframe
    :param subset: target column to be splitted
    :param subset_explode: the subset to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values 
    :param split_value: Value to split. 
        # split('\s') is almost always wrong because it creates empty strings if there is more than one space separator,
        # use split('\s+) or simple split()
    :return: splitted dataset with new rows
    '''
    return df.assign(text=df[subset].str.split(split_value)).explode(subset_explode)
```

### Example of the correct output:

```py
# DATAFRAME INPUT
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'emotion': ['joy', 'fear', 'sadness'],
    'text': ['falling love', 'involved traffic accident', 'lost person']
})

# EXPECTED OUTPUT                                                                      
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'emotion': ['joy', 'joy', 'fear', 'fear', 'fear', 'fear' 'sadness', 'sadness', 'sadness'],
    'text': ['falling', 'love', 'involved', 'traffic', 'accident', 'lost', 'person', 'meant']
})

# This will give the correct ouptut
splitting_rows(df, subset='text', subset_explode='text')
```

### Current problem with the dataframe

```py
    Emotion Text                                                text
0   joy     period falling love time met especially met lo...   [period, falling, love, time, met, lo...
1   fear    involved traffic accident                           [involved, traffic, accident]
2   anger   driving home several days hard work motorist a...   [driving, home, several, days, hard, work, mot...
3   sadness lost person meant                                   [lost, person, meant]
```

I tried to recreate the dataframe, appending each column to a list and each list to a new dataframe (there's no nan values) to get something similar to the first working example, but it was the same.

I'm using [this dataframe](https://github.com/Y4rd13/datasets/blob/main/df_test.csv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the `text` named argument in the `assign` method. The named argument refers to the column name. In your dataframe you have `text` and on the online one it is `Text`.
The correct approach would to build the name argument in `apply` dynamically based on the value of the `subset` parameter.

Replace your return statement with this one :

```py
return df.assign(**{subset:df[subset].str.split(split_value)}).explode(subset_explode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I first split the data and expanded the columns, then I joined the expanded columns with the original, so I could get the emotion variable connected:

```
df_expand = df['text'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df_merge = pd.concat([df, df_expand], axis=1).drop('text', axis=1)
```

After that I put in a list the names of the variables in a list and dropped the emotion, this way I had only the names of the expanded columns:

```
lc = list(df_merge.columns)
lc.remove('emotion')
```

Then I used melt to unpivot the values of the expanded dataset

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df_merge, id_vars=['emotion'], value_vars=lc).drop('variable', axis=1)
```

dropped the values that were null and sorted the value for a cleaner view

```
df_melt = df_melt[df_melt['value'].notnull()]
df_melt.sort_values('emotion')
```

This is what I got

[image]